# MongoDB/Mongoose: append related records to each aggreation result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Given the following Mongo collection called "members"

```
{
  {name: "Joe", hobby: "Food"}, {name: "Lyn", hobby: "Food"},
  {name: "Rex", hobby: "Play"}, {name: "Rex", hobby: "Shop"},...
}
```

I have an aggregation query that returns a paged set of records along with metadata for the total records found:

```js
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      pipe1: [{ $count: 'count' }],
      pipe2: [{ $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 4 }],
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$pipe1',
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: '$pipe1.count',
      results: '$pipe2',
    },
  },
])
```

This gives me:

```
{count: 454, results: [<First 4 records here>]}
```

I am now trying to add to each record, an array of all member names that have the same hobby. So for the collection above, something like:

```
{
  count: 454,
  results: [
    {name: "Joe", hobby: "Food", fanClub: ["Joe", "Lyn", "Alfred"]},
    {name: "Lyn", hobby: "Food", fanClub: ["Joe", "Lyn", "Alfred"]},
    {name: "Rex", hobby: "Play", fanClub: ["Rex"]},
    {name: "Rex", hobby: "Shop", fanClub: ["Rex", "Rita"]}
  ]
}
```

I can't figure out how to run the follow up query within the aggregate.  I've tried:

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      pipe1: [{ $count: 'count' }],
      pipe2: [
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 2 },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'members',
            pipeline: [{ $match: { hobby: '$hobby' } }],
            as: 'fanClub',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$pipe1',
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: '$pipe1.count',
      results: '$pipe2',
    },
  },
])
```

Alas, the `fanClub` array is always empty.

#### Update 1

If I hardcode the hobby, for instance replace

```
{ $match: { hobby: '$hobby' }
```

with

```
{ $match: { hobby: 'Food' }
```

Then I do get results and all the `fanClub` arrays contain the results for Joe, Lyn and Alfred.  So I must not be referring to the value within the pipeline correctly

Comment: `{
  {name: "Joe", hobby: "Food"}, {name: "Lyn", hobby: "Food"},
  {name: "Rex", hobby: "Play"}, {name: "Rex", hobby: "Shop"}
}` --> Are these exactly four documents ? that means each user can have different documents based on their hobby ?

Comment: @srinivasy Yes.  The same name appear in multiple documents tied to different hobbies.  so Rex can be bound to Play and separately to Shop.  Likewise, the same hobby can have two users in different documents; so both Joe and Lyn can be bound to Food in separate documents

Comment: You've missed `let` attribute for uncorrelated lookup: `from:..., let:{hobby:"$hobby"}, pipeline:[{$match:{$expr:{$eq:["$hobby", "$$hobby"]}}}]`

Comment: @Valijon if this is an answer, would you please write it as an answer so you can get credit if it works? It's difficult to make out your reply here for someone inexperienced like me.

Comment: Ohh, I've not seen there is a query, which look similar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.membersHobby.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            pipe1: [{ $count: 'count' }],
            pipe2: [{
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "membersHobby",
                    let: { hobby: "$hobby" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match:
                                { $expr: { $eq: ["$hobby", "$$hobby"] } }
                        },
                        { $project: { name: 1, _id: 0 } }
                    ],
                    as: "fanClub"
                }
            }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 4 }]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$pipe1'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            count: '$pipe1.count',
            results: '$pipe2'
        }
    }
])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "count" : 4,
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e20a63ed3c98f2a7100fd4a"),
            "name" : "Joe",
            "hobby" : "Food",
            "fanClub" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Joe"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Lyn"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e20a63ed3c98f2a7100fd4b"),
            "name" : "Lyn",
            "hobby" : "Food",
            "fanClub" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Joe"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Lyn"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e20a63ed3c98f2a7100fd4c"),
            "name" : "Rex",
            "hobby" : "Play",
            "fanClub" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Rex"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e20a63ed3c98f2a7100fd4d"),
            "name" : "Rex",
            "hobby" : "Shop",
            "fanClub" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Rex"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer!  thumbs up.  Since Valijon posted the solution first, I'll give him a chance to write it up as an answer and select it if he does a good job of explaining.  If he doesn't after a while I will choose yours.

Comment: @BeetleJuice : sure, So does this answer seems exactly same or do you need the `fansclub` as an array of strings or as an array of objects ?

Comment: An array of strings actually, but I figured that would be a separate question

Answer (score 1):

If **@srinivasy**'s answer meets your requierements, please grant my points him :)

If you want to get such structure:

```
{
  count: 454,
  results: [
    {name: "Joe", hobby: "Food", fanClub: ["Joe", "Lyn", "Alfred"]},
    {name: "Lyn", hobby: "Food", fanClub: ["Joe", "Lyn", "Alfred"]},
    {name: "Rex", hobby: "Play", fanClub: ["Rex"]},
    {name: "Rex", hobby: "Shop", fanClub: ["Rex", "Rita"]}
  ]
}
```

Use this query (`$reduce` is used to return single value, in you case `fanClub` as array):

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      pipe1: [
        {
          $count: "count"
        }
      ],
      pipe2: [
        {
          $skip: 0
        },
        {
          $limit: 4
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "members",
            let: {
              hobby: "$hobby"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$hobby",
                      "$$hobby"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "fanClub"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$pipe1"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: "$pipe1.count",
      results: {
        $map: {
          input: "$pipe2",
          as: "pipe2",
          in: {
            _id: "$$pipe2._id",
            hobby: "$$pipe2.hobby",
            name: "$$pipe2.name",
            fanClub: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$$pipe2.fanClub",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    [
                      "$$this.name"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tMn8AB9Nsq1)